# SSH timeout when creating vagrant box with packer

Tags: vagrant, packer

I use the following template to create vagrant box with packer. However, i get error "Build 'vmware-vmx' errored: Timeout waiting for SSH.". How to fix this?

```
{
 "builders": [{
 "type": "vmware-vmx",
 "source_path": "/path/to/a/vm.vmx",
 "ssh_username": "root",
 "ssh_password": "root",
 "ssh_wait_timeout": "30s",
 "shutdown_command": "echo 'packer' | sudo -S shutdown -P now"
}],
"provisioners": [{
   "type": "shell",
   "inline": ["echo 'my additional provisioning steps'"]
 }],
"post-processors": [{
   "type": "vagrant",
   "keep_input_artifact": true,
   "output": "mycentos.box"
 }]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set headless parameter of the builder to false. Start the build and watch out for an error. If no error occurs then increase the timeout parameter. 30s is a bit small for instantiating, cloning and running the vm.

in your case:

```
"builders": [{
 "type": "vmware-vmx",
 "source_path": "/path/to/a/vm.vmx",
 "ssh_username": "root",
 "ssh_password": "root",
 "headless" : false,
 "ssh_wait_timeout": "1000s",
 "shutdown_command": "echo 'packer' | sudo -S shutdown -P now"
}]
```

Comment: This was helpful. Its really shows what is going wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't need the SSH connection during the provisioning process you can switch it off. See the packer documentation about [communicator](https://www.packer.io/docs/communicators), there you see the option `none` to switch of the communication between host and guest.

```json
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "vmware-vmx",
      "communicator": "none"
    }
  ]
}
```

Packer Builders [DOCU vmware-vmx](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/vmware-vmx.html)